# Why does DateTime::createFromFormat() returns a boolean and shows data missing error?

Tags: php, datetime

When I run these code. I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool in /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/www/login/user/save.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/www/login/user/save.php on line 18.

Is there something wrong with the `format()` function?

When I use this:

```php
var_dump($tmp);
var_dump(DateTime::CreateFromFormat("m/d/Y", $_POST['start_date']));
var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors("m/d/Y", $_POST['start_date']));
```

try to get the error message, it shows:

```php
bool(false)
bool(false)
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=> int(0)
  ["warnings"]=> array(0) { }
  ["error_count"]=> int(1)
  ["errors"]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(12) "Data missing"
  }
}
```

```php
$_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);
$tmp = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("m/d/Y", $_POST['start_date']);
//var_dump....
$start_date = $tmp->format("Y-m-d");
$tmp = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("m/d/Y", $_POST['end_date']);
$end_date = $tmp->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: Most likely your `$_POST['start_date']` isn't in the desired format: `m/d/Y`

Comment: Read the documentation: it returns `FALSE` if it gets an error.

Comment: FYI, `DateTime::getLastErrors()` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST['start_date']`?

Comment: Make sure your code that processes the form is in something like `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` -- replace `submit` with the actual name of your submit button.

Comment: when I do var_dump($_POST['start_date']); and got string(10) "09/26/2019"

Comment: `$tmp = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", "09/26/2019");  var_dump($tmp->format("Y-m-d"));` 
Works For Me: `string(10) "2019-09-26"`

Comment: Try to change `CreateFromFormat` to `createFromFormat` (mind the lower-case 'c')

Comment: @digijay in PHP it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fatal error appears because of data is missing so it returns bool(false). If I type a specific time in the front page form and then front page will show the data: 
object(DateTime)#7 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-09-30 15:09:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }. And it works well to insert to database. Thank you for all your help and guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to begin the function correct case with a lower 'c'.

[DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$tmp = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $_POST['start_date']);
```

This method returns either a DateTime object **or** false on failure.
In you your case it looks like `$tmp` is false (due to wrong function call?), and you can not call format() on a boolean, what the error message says.

So check before applying.

```
if($tmp) $start_date = $tmp->format("Y-m-d");
```